# Why does my code keep getting the error: <identifier> expected?

Tags: java, identifier

Okay so, I'm trying to do my programming homework and it's KILLING ME, because the online compilers I use keep giving me the same indentifier expected error, but I tried everything to fix it, and it never does!
Please, please explain me what's wrong!

It gives me this exact error:
/ListadeExercicio1.java:1: error:  expected
import:java.io.*;

Here's my code so far (it's in pt-br, please don't mind):

````
public class ListadeExercicio1 {
  public static void main (String args[]) {
    String s="";
    float num1=0;
    int numin1=0;
    int numin2=0;
    float cubo=0;
    float resto=0;
    float quadrado=0;
    float raizquadrada=0;
    float triplo=0;
    float acrescimo=0;
    float decrecimo=0;

    DataInputStream dado; 

  try {
    System.out.println("Insira o primeiro número para as operações:");
    dado=new DataInputStream(System.in); 
    s=dado.readLine(); 
    num1=Float.parseFloat(s); 

    System.out.println("Insira o segundo número para as operações:");
    dado=new DataInputStream(System.in);  
    s=dado.readLine(); 
    nota2=Integer.parseInt(s);

    System.out.println("Insira o terceiro número para as operações:");
    dado=new DataInputStream(System.in);  
    s=dado.readLine(); 
    nota2=Integer.parseInt(s);

//Cálculos

    cubo=num1*num1*num1;


    System.out.println("Media: " + media);
  } 
   catch (IOException erro) {
    System.out.println("Houve um erro na entrada de dados :(" +erro.toString());
  } 
}
}```
````

Comment: The problem could be in your imports, can you show them?

Comment: Sure, I only used this: import:java.io.*;

Comment: Should be `import java.io.*;` without the  `:` unless that's just a typo in your question.

Comment: Oh my good lord, thank you so f*ng much
I can not believe this was my mistake :')

Comment: Please answer your question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

You are probably missing import statements. Try adding these to your code,

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.*;
```

In addition to that, you also need to define variables `media` and `nota2`. You cannot initialize variable without defining it in Java.

Comment: Yeah, those variables are just here because I actually recycled my code lol
But I got it to work with import java.io.*, thank you! <3

Comment: You never need to import `java.lang`. It's automatically imported, by specification.

Comment: Online compilers generally not import `java.lang` by default. Also marking it as an answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you should've imported `java.io.*;` because you're using classes from that package and you didn't.

You should read about [Java packages](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch02_11.htm).

Also, I noticed that you tagged your question with both Java and JavaScript. Please note that, in spite of the names being similar, these are actually completely unrelated languages.

Comment: Oh, noted! Will edit my tags. Thank you for your help!